# View count history

Tags: support, data-dump, views

I am using the Stack Overflow data dump (located at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) for research that involves looking at the popularity history of posts, and I have a question regarding view counts.

The dump contains a Votes.xml file with information on when a vote has been cast and to which post, which allows one to construct a time series of post score over time for all posts. Is there a similar thing available for post view counts? As far as I checked, the only data available on view counts is the count in Posts.xml for questions, which is the current (at the time of the snapshot) total view count - there seems to be no history available.

Comment: Nope, ViewCount is not available and I'm not even sure if it is available internally. IIRC SE Staff can only obtain it by reconstructing the viewcount by parsing the log files.